# Mapping JSON to MUI cards not returning any UI elements or errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, material-ui

I have the following JSON which I want to map to MUI Cards.  I am not getting any error messages but nothing is being displayed.  The `console.log(questionGroups)` only displays the JSON after changing some unrelated code to cause a live reload.

```
    const [questionGroups, setQuestionGroups] = useState("");

    const fetchQuestionGroups= async () => {
        setQuestionGroups(
            await fetch(`API_LINK`).then((response) => response.json())
        );
        console.log(questionGroups);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchQuestionGroups();
    }, []);
...
            <Box className={classes.cards}>
                {questionGroups?.displaygroups?.IntakeQuestion?.map((group, groupIndex) => {
                    return (
                        <Card className={classes.card1}>
                            <CardHeader title={group.GroupName} />
                        </Card>
                    );
                })}
            </Box>
```

This is a sample of my JSON:

```
{
  "displaygroups": {
    "IntakeQuestions": [
      {
        "GroupId": 11,
        "GroupName": "Group 1",
        "SizingId": null,
        "OwnerName": "Jane Doe",
        "Questions": 0,
        "Answered": null,
        "Validated": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use && instead of ?

```
<Box className={classes.cards}>
    {questionGroups &&
        questionGroups.displaygroups &&
        questionGroups.displaygroups.IntakeQuestions.map((group, groupIndex) => {
            return (
                <Card className={classes.card1}>
                    <CardHeader title={group.GroupName} />
                </Card>
            );
        })}
</Box>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the state once the data is available.

```
const fetchQuestionGroups= async () => {
     const data = await fetch(`API_LINK`)
     const temp  = response.json()
     setQuestionGroups(temp);
     console.log(questionGroups);
  };
```

Comment: Unfortunately this results in the same outcome

Comment: if it isn't working then kindly paste complete code.